# Golang - How to delete orphan metrics from Prometheus

Tags: go, prometheus, metrics

I have a Go program that gets a Prometheus time series to dynamically inject a label on it and then exposes them back on "/metrics" for Prometheus to scrape again.

The problem I have right now is that whenever a metric stops reporting values, instead of being deleted the metric goes on and on with the same last value that it had.

**Example:**
I have this time series at 10:00

```
new_billing_raw:memory_allocated:sum{billed_namespace="monitoring",exported_job="prometheus",task="prometheus",task_group="monitoring",uuaa="CD34"} 300
```

If at 10:01 I stop the exporter from which Prometheus receives these labels and values, the value of this metric will be null.
Instead of null, my program will report the last value, 300 in this case, indefinitely until I restart my program.

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: How do you create these metrics? Usually you would implement [Collector](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector) and simply stop sending obsolete metrics, but it sounds like you're doing something else.

Comment: What I do basically is:  

1. Execute a custom query against Prometheus with some custom query logic (sum without, label replace...)  
2. Based on this query I construct a new metric, with a different name, and then I "copy" the values of the query into the new metric with `newMetric.With(seriesLabelSet).Set(seriesValue)`  
3. Expose on "/metrics" via `http.Handle(Path, promhttp.Handler())`  

(I'm pretty new to Go so Its very probable that I'm doing this wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the built-in metric implementations in this case (prometheus.NewGauge and so on). These never forget a label value and they cannot be de-registered. Instead, write a new type that implements [prometheus.Collector](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector) and register an instance of that type. Move the code that queries prometheus into the Collect method of that new type.

[From the docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#collectors):

> When implementing the collector for your exporter, you should never use the usual direct instrumentation approach and then update the metrics on each scrape.
>
> Rather create new metrics each time. In Go this is done with MustNewConstMetric in your Collect() method. [...]
>
> The reason for this is two-fold. Firstly, two scrapes could happen at the same time, and direct instrumentation uses what are effectively file-level global variables, so you’ll get race conditions. Secondly, if a label value disappears, it’ll still be exported.

Here is a rough draft:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
)

func main() {
    prometheus.MustRegister(&MyCollector{})
}

var memAllocatedDesc = prometheus.NewDesc(
    "new_billing_raw:memory_allocated:sum",
    "TODO: help",
    []string{"billed_namespace", "exported_job", "task", "task_group", "uuaa"},
    nil, // constant labels
)

// add descriptions for more metrics as necessary


type MyCollector struct{}

// Describe implements prometheus.Collector. It sends to ch descriptions of
// all metrics that Collect could ever possibly produce over c's entire
// lifetime.
//
// See also prometheus.DescribeByCollect for a possible shortcut
// implementation.
func (c *MyCollector) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {
    ch <- memAllocatedDesc
}

func (c *MyCollector) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {
    // TODO: query upstream prometheus

    ch <- prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(
        memAllocatedDesc,
        prometheus.GaugeValue,
        300,           // value
        "default",     // billed_namespace
        "code-server", // exported_job
        "code-serer",  // task
        "code-serer",  // task_group
        "GBT5",        // uuaa
    )

    // Repeat as necessary, for each metric and label set.
}
```

Describe is called once, when the collector is registered. Collect is called for every request to /metrics.

Querying the upstream prometheus in Collect ensures that every scrape sees up-to-date values. If querying the upstream prometheus instance on each scrape is too expensive (unlikely), do the queries asynchronously and store them in some sort of concurrency-safe data structure, then use this data structure in Collect. The key here is that only metrics sent to the `chan prometheus.Metric` appear in the scrape response.